# Derivative of $Ax$ when $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$A$ is just a scalar.

Should the derivative of $Ax$ be $A$ or $A^d$?

Context: I'm trying to evaluate this integral

$$\int\varphi(2^n(x-y))\varphi(2^n(x-y))\mathrm{d}x$$

and I know that

$$\int\varphi(2^n(x-y))\varphi(2^n(x-y))\mathrm{d}(2^n(x-y))=1.$$

$\varphi$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$.

Since

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}2^n(x-y) = 2^n,$$
we have
$$2^{-n}\mathrm{d}(2^n(x-y))= \mathrm{d}x.$$

Substituting into the original integral,

$$\int\varphi(2^n(x-y))\varphi(2^n(x-y))\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=\int\varphi(2^n(x-y))\varphi(2^n(x-y))2^{-n}\mathrm{d}(2^n(x-y))$$
$$=2^{-n}.$$

Have I done this substitution correctly?

Comment: At any point $x$, the derivative is the map $h\in \Bbb R^n \mapsto Ah$, i.e. the map itself.

Comment: @OpenBall Which is true even when $A$ is a matrix.

Comment: @Arthur sure ${}$

Comment: @OpenBall thanks for your comment. I've edited the question to add some more context, is what I've done alright?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not computing the derivative, but applying correctly the change of variables formula.

We have that: $$D Ax = A$$ which can be simply interpreted as: $$\frac{d}{dx_j}(Ax)_{i} = A_{i,j}$$ In the examples you consider we just have $A = \lambda I,$ since we are looking at substitutions of the kind $x = \lambda y.$ Now I invite you to check out the [Change of Variable Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution). Then you will see that $$dx = |det(\lambda I)| dy = \lambda^d dy.$$